# Is it possible to use an array variable in the return section of the edit function of a Gutenberg block?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I can fetch the data from WordPress using the REST API and display it in the SelectControl in the return section of the edit function like in the following:

```
attributes:
    {
        queryid:
        {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },
        jsondata:
        {
            type: 'array'
        },
    },
    
    edit: ( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) => {
        const fetchSearchQueries = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`http://${ window.location.hostname }/corporagrid/wp-json/corpora/v1/query`, {
                cache: 'no-cache',
                headers: {
                    'user-agent': 'WP Block',
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                },
                method: 'GET',
                redirect: 'follow',
                referrer: 'no-referrer'
            }).then(returned => {
                    if ( returned.ok ) {
                        return returned;
                    }
                    throw new Error( 'Network response was not ok.' );
                }
            );
            let searchQueries = await response.json();
            let searchQueriesArray = [];
            searchQueries.forEach( searchQuery => {
                searchQueriesArray.push( { value: searchQuery.id, label: searchQuery.name } );
            } );

            setAttributes( { jsondata: searchQueriesArray } );
        };
        fetchSearchQueries();
        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                <SelectControl
                    label={__('Selected Search Query:', 'test')}
                    options={ attributes.jsondata }
                    value={attributes.queryid}
                    onChange={(newval) => setAttributes({ queryid: newval })}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I had to set my array attribute to the array variable I created but actually I don't need to use this array attribute. Since I cannot use the array variable in the select control I found this solution. I receive undefined variable error when I use the array itself. Is there a way to accomplish this without setting the attribute to the array?

Answer (score 0):

As `attributes.jsondata` is undefined/has no valid default value on first load, the `<SelectControl>` cannot be rendered, so to avoid the redundant `jsondata` attribute, replace:

```js
...
searchQueries.forEach( searchQuery => {
    searchQueriesArray.push( { value: searchQuery.id, label: searchQuery.name } 
    );
});

setAttributes( { jsondata: searchQueriesArray } );
...
    <SelectControl
        label={__('Selected Search Query:', 'test')}
        options={ attributes.jsondata }
        value={attributes.queryid}
        onChange={(newval) => setAttributes({ queryid: newval })}
    />
```

with:

```js
...
let searchQueriesArray = !Array.isArray(searchQueries)
    ? searchQueries : searchQueries.map((searchQuery) => ({
        label: searchQuery.name,
        value: searchQuery.id
    }));
...
   <SelectControl
        label={__('Selected Search Query:', 'test')}
        options={ searchQueriesArray } // Replaced attribute with variable
        value={attributes.queryid}
        onChange={(newval) => setAttributes({ queryid: newval })}
    />
```

If `searchQueries` has not yet resolved, it contains `[]`. Once resolved,  it will contain the data to be mapped into `{label, value}` for the `<SelectControl>` to render safely.

Comment: Unfortunately, the block encountered an error and couldn't be viewed after I made the suggested changes like the following:

Comment: I made the necessary changes like: `/* commented here
   let searchQueriesArray = [];
   searchQueries.forEach( searchQuery => {
    searchQueriesArray.push( { value: searchQuery.id, label: searchQuery.name } );
   } );
   setAttributes( { jsondata: searchQueriesArray } );
  commented here */
   let searchQueriesArray = !Array.isArray(searchQueries)
    ? searchQueries : searchQueries.map((searchQuery) => ({
     label: searchQuery.name,
     value: searchQuery.id
    }));
  };
  fetchSearchQueries();`

Comment: I also made the changes in the select control